# Use tweepy to get Twitter videos from user timeline

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

When using tweepy to collect video tweets, generally the Status object returned has an `extended_entities` attribute that contains media information like the direct link to the mp4 file.

It appears however that statuses with Amplify videos (amp.twimg.com) are missing this `extended_entities` attribute and so I am having trouble collecting the media url. They have a link to the video that is fine if you are navigating with a browser (http://amp.twimg.com/v/50bac95c-1508-40c6-a0fc-c1b26a53a3b8 for example) but this is not very useful if I just want the mp4 file.

Is there a way to collect the mp4 file from Amplify videos using tweepy? Why do these videos not have the same media information as other twitter videos?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the [official documentation,](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/upcoming-changes-to-tweets) you have to opt into the extended mode via a request parameter:

> "Any endpoints that return Tweets will accept a new tweet_mode request parameter. Valid request values are compat and extended, which give compatibility mode and extended mode, respectively."

So maybe you'll have better results if you explicitly pass tweet_mode='extended'. Not sure if this has been implemented in Tweepy yet. Just check the sourcecode.